# Iterating a case_when statement over multiple pairs of columns

Tags: r, dplyr, case-when

I have a dataframe with 27 pairs of columns, the first in the pair is a character vector with the narcotics prescription name ("codein", "hydrocodone", "hydromorphone", etc) and the second column is a numerical vector with dosage, I would like to calculate an oral morphine equivalent using the dosage and a conversion factor based on the prescription. the names and conversion factors are as follows.

codeine: 0.15
hydrocodone: 1
hydromorphone: 4
oxycodone: 1.5
tramadol: 0.1
morphine: 1

I wrote the code to perform this action with a single pair of columns, and it is fairly simple using a case_when statement

```
ome_3 <- ome_2%>%mutate(morphine_eq_1 = case_when(str_detect(Pre_Op_Drug_Name_1, "orco")~Pre_Op_Dose_1__mg_,
                                                str_detect(Pre_Op_Drug_Name_1, "ydrocodone")~Pre_Op_Dose_1__mg_,
                                                str_detect(Pre_Op_Drug_Name_1, "orphone")~Pre_Op_Dose_1__mg_ * 4,
                                                str_detect(Pre_Op_Drug_Name_1, "xycodone")~Pre_Op_Dose_1__mg_ * 1.5,
                                                str_detect(Pre_Op_Drug_Name_1, "ramadol")~Pre_Op_Dose_1__mg_/10,
                                                str_detect(Pre_Op_Drug_Name_1, "ilaudid")~Pre_Op_Dose_1__mg_ * 4,
                                                str_detect(Pre_Op_Drug_Name_1, "xycontin")~Pre_Op_Dose_1__mg_ * 1.5))
```

But how do I iterate the same mutating(case_when) statement over all 27 pairs of columns to produce 27 new columns of the morphine equivalents? I am at a loss after a day, have tried a for loop or rudimentary metaprogramming to no avail.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: If you want to use the same, then consider `mutate_at(vars(yourcolumnnames), ~ case_when(str_detect(., ""` i.e. change the Pre_Op_Drug_Name_1 to `.`